# If $R$ is a ring and $I$ and $J$ are ideals, then if $\operatorname{rad}(I) + \operatorname{rad}(J) = R$, then $I + J = R$

Tags: commutative-algebra

How can I show that if $R$ is a ring and $I$ and $J$ are ideals, then if $\operatorname{rad}(I) + \operatorname{rad}(J) = R$, then $I + J = R$? This has had me stumped for some time, which is frustrating as I imagine it has a fairly elementary solution.

Assume $R$ is commutative with an identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $I+J\neq R$, then $I+J$ is contained in a maximal ideal $M$, hence...

> $I, J $ are contained in $M$, hence $rad(I), rad(J)$ and $rad(I)+rad(J)$ are contained in $M$. So, $rad(I)+rad(J)\neq R$ and we've proven the contrapositive.

The nice part about this is that it works even if the radical is the Jacobson radical, and you don't have to do any binomial expansion.

Comment: I've been trying this for a while now, and although your comment didn't solve the problem directly for me it somehow inspired me to find this solution: $1 \in rad(I) + rad(J) \implies 1^k=1\in I + J$. And then you're done. (I actually did find it before that other answer was posted haha)

Comment: @Daven Well, since I thought it should convince anyone nearly instantly, I've gone ahead and completed my argument as a spoiler. I think it's a rather useful way of solving the problem. It's certainly nice to have an element-free solution to the problem. (Nothing against elements, really.)

Comment: This seems like a nice solution, however it is not obvious to me why $I+J$ being in $M$ means that $rad(I)$ is in $M$.

Comment: @Daven Do you know that $rad(I)$ is equal to the intersection of all prime ideals containing $I$?  M is a prime ideal containing both I and J

Answer (score 3):

If $\operatorname{rad}(I)+\operatorname{rad}(I)=R$, then we can write
$$1=x+y$$
with $x\in \operatorname{rad}(I)$ and $y\in\operatorname{rad}(J)$, say $x^m\in I$ and $y^n\in J$. Then consider what happens if we raise both sides of $1=x+y$ to the $(m+n)$th power.

Comment: Actually the $(m+n-1)$th power suffices.

Comment: @Jakob Werner: good point, though of course what's important is that some power works.